# Power BI Sum cells grouped by same ID

Tags: powerbi

How can I make a formula which sums all the cells which have the same ID?

[image]
[image]

Edit: Both of these columns are in the same table. I need a new column which calculates the sum of all the hours with the same ID.

Comment: Your questions is a bit unclear. Do you have to have a measure or are you happy with a just visual? Are the two columns in the picture in the same table? If not what is their relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, I would create a new summery table:

```
SummeryTable = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'TableName';
    'TableName'[ID];
    "Time_summed"; SUM('TableName'[TimeColumn])
)
```

Then you will end up with a table with distinct [ID] on each row and the sum of all hours corresponding to this ID from the original data table. Which you can use to create a relationship with the original table.

EDIT_1:

Yes you can if you use a calculated column like this:

```
SumTime = 
VAR thisID = [ID]
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM('TableName'[TimeColumn]);
    ALL('Tablename');
    'TableName'[ID] = thisID
)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a new table? Just with a new column in my existing table with a formula?

Comment: Is there a way we could speak more directly? I could use more of your knowledge :)

Comment: Haha thanks @PLATINUM, why not keep the questions here so that everyone can learn from anyone's question. Otherwise I'd have to charge you by the hour for private tutoring ;-)