# Excel Formula to Power BI with DAX - Summing multiple values with same ID

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

Im having trouble trying to convert this formula to DAX. I need a new column in my table with the output of this formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;Horas_totales!$A$2:$C$10000;3;FALSE);0)
```

**This is what A2 is.** (Sheet1)
[image]

In the formula you will see a sheet named **horas_totales** with a range of cells but this is from a dynamic table which adds up all the **column P** (see pic) with the same **ID**.

**This is the data the dynamic table uses.** (Sheet2)

[image]

So I need to **find the ID in A2 from sheet1** in the sheet2 and add up all the numbers with that same ID.

Comment: I'm confused - you're asking for DAX, but showing Excel sheets.... Can you please [edit] your question to show your TABLES. It looks like all you need to do is create a relationship between the two tables on field `ID de incidencia` and then use a simple `SUM` function, but your table structure isn't clear.

Comment: My power bi tables have the same information as the excel sheets. I imported the excel with that data and have to replicate the columns from my excel with formulas to power bi

Comment: If Olly's solution doesn't help, maybe this post can? 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337848/power-bi-sum-cells-grouped-by-same-id/55339562#55339562)

Comment: Lol, thats my colleagues question hahaha. I didnt know he asked about this. Seems like it worked, sorry!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Power BI Sum cells grouped by same ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337848/power-bi-sum-cells-grouped-by-same-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a relationship between the two tables on field `ID de incidencia` then you can simply use:

```
NewColumn = CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table2[Total horas laborables] ) )
```

Worked example PBIX file: https://pwrbi.com/so_55393176/